# A safe way to display pdf in web

Tags: pdf, web, pdf.js, aspose, pdftron

How to encrypt pdf files and display them in web in a way that the data is encrypted in the inspect element and no one can see the direct link so that cannot be downloaded.
Is there any web service or software to do this?

Comment: "data is encrypted in the inspect element" sounds like you are looking for runtime client side decryption. Though why is having the PDF in the DOM even a requirement? "no one can see the direct link so that cannot be downloaded." all network traffic is visible to the client, so you would have to find a means for your server to authenticate desired access from undesired access (there are many ways to do this).

Comment: "Is there any web service or software to do this?" Stackoverflow is not the appropriate place to ask this. You should ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want prevent them from save?